# How can I remove a folder name from the URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I'm looking for a way to remove a folder name from the url, without any side effects. I've structured my website in such a way that all pages apart from the homepage are placed in a folder called 'structure'. So for example:

- [www.example.com/structure/page1/](http://www.example.com/structure/page1/)
- [www.example.com/structure/page2/](http://www.example.com/structure/page2/)
- [www.example.com/structure/page3/](http://www.example.com/structure/page3/)

Each page has local CSS and JS files, specifically for those pages. So the directories of these files also include the structure folder (e.g. [www.example.com/structure/page1/style/style.css](http://www.example.com/structure/page1/style/style.css)). The structure folder should also be removed from these.

What I'm trying to do is modify my .htaccess file (assuming this is the right way) to remove the 'structure' folder from the URL, without any side effects. The folder is there for me to structure a website with multiple pages, but should not affect the user once the website is live. The URL should simply be [www.example.com/page1/](http://www.example.com/page1/)

I've found several solutions which lead me to currently using the following code:

note: this is a collection of code I found online and tested, I cannot write Apache code myself.

```
# Removes "structure" directory from URL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        
        # Removes "structure" directory from URL, but does not redirect the old URL
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /structure/$1 [L]

        # Redirect any "direct" requests to the `/structure` directory
        # to remove the directory from the URL-path.
        # Also removes the ".php" extension (if present)
        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^structure(/.*?)(?:\.php)?$ $1 [R=301,L]

        # Check if the requested resource exists in the /structure subdirectory.
        # If so, rewrite the request to that subdirectory.
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/structure/$1 -f
        RewriteRule (.+\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif))$ /structure/$1 [L]

        # Check if the requested PHP file exists in the /structure subdirectory
        # if requesting a URL that does not already have a file extension.
        # NB: Assumes the URL-path does not otherwise contain dots.
        # If so, rewrite the request to that subdirectory appending ".php"
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/structure/$1.php -f
        RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /structure/$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It seems to do the trick for the most part, except that is messes up the 404 page (which I have in my rootfolder and set the following way). If I go to a random URL, say "www.example.com/laisdjoapidj/", I get an internal server error message, instead of the 404 page.

```
# Customize what Apache returns to the client in case of an error.
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

My question is: how can I fix this?